# Bootstrap Website - Misalignment in header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap based HTML page but I don't know why the left hand side menu is misaligned wrt the black header strip. I think it's a minor typo but I cannot find it. Can anyone help?

```
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Left hand side menu --> 

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            <!-- right hand side menu -->
              <ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
                </form>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

... main part of the website  ...
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `<div class="container">` inside your navbar should be `class="container-fluid"`. So instead of

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
```

try

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aF3aJ/)

Comment: +1. `.container`s are not nestable by default because of padding.

Comment: Thanks both. Now it works. BTW is there a good book on creating websites via Bootstrap or should I go through official documentation?